Stuck on Bios screen
I switched to kernel version 6.8.0-47-generic, because the nvidia client version was (automatically?) updated to that version, so the driver would no longer run.
Now it gets stuck on a bios screen, but not the first one. I usually only get the bios screen on one monitor, but now the screen goes black after that, then the bios screen appears on both monitors. As far as I can tell nothing happens from now on.
If I boot to recovery mode, then resume the boot, everything works. (It boots, the graphics driver works, etc. I don't notice anything out of the ordinary). I should mention though, that evertime I've done this I spent several minutes looking at journalctl/dmesg logs before resuming.
I am by no means familiar with these log messages and I might well have missed something important.
However, this stood out to me:
[  738.264864] INFO: task systemd-udevd:407 blocked for more than 614 seconds.
[  738.264866]       Tainted: P           O       6.8.0-47-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  738.264868] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  738.264870] task:systemd-udevd   state:D stack:0     pid:407   tgid:407   ppid:386    flags:0x00000006
[  738.264875] Call Trace:
[  738.264877]  <TASK>
[  738.264879]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6a0
[  738.264885]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[  738.264890]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[  738.264893]  __mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x3f8/0x7a0
[  738.264898]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264902]  ? __memcg_slab_post_alloc_hook+0x18e/0x230
[  738.264907]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[  738.264911]  mutex_lock+0x3c/0x50
[  738.264915]  uevent_show+0xc4/0x170
[  738.264919]  dev_attr_show+0x1d/0x70
[  738.264923]  sysfs_kf_seq_show+0xa3/0x110
[  738.264926]  kernfs_seq_show+0x27/0x40
[  738.264930]  seq_read_iter+0x135/0x4a0
[  738.264935]  kernfs_fop_read_iter+0x34/0x40
[  738.264939]  vfs_read+0x258/0x390
[  738.264945]  ksys_read+0x73/0x100
[  738.264949]  __x64_sys_read+0x19/0x30
[  738.264952]  x64_sys_call+0x23f0/0x24b0
[  738.264955]  do_syscall_64+0x81/0x170
[  738.264961]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264964]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x86/0x260
[  738.264968]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264971]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
[  738.264975]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264978]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
[  738.264982]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264985]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
[  738.264988]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264991]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
[  738.264995]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.264998]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
[  738.265001]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.265004]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
[  738.265008]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[  738.265012]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
[  738.265014] RIP: 0033:0x77bce91147e2
[  738.265020] RSP: 002b:00007fffbbc8af88 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
[  738.265023] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000001008 RCX: 000077bce91147e2
[  738.265025] RDX: 0000000000001008 RSI: 00005dd90875d140 RDI: 0000000000000010
[  738.265027] RBP: 00005dd90875d140 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00005dd90875d140
[  738.265029] R10: 000077bce921acf0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000010
[  738.265031] R13: 0000000000001007 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 00007fffbbc8afb0
[  738.265036]  </TASK>

What can I do to boot normally again?

It might be a faulty driver. Try using recovery mode to remove some optional drivers and check if that solves it.
